# Dúvida em relação a tag mvc

Tags: debate, tags

Me deparei com esta pergunta hoje:

[Problemas com Web.Config](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30695/problemas-com-web-config)

Uma das tags da questão é [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc). Obviamente, esta questão não trata de MVC conforme o descrito na wiki da tag. Entretanto, conheço diversas pessoas que associam mvc ao framework da Microsoft.

Neste caso, devo editar e remover a tag [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) da pergunta? E em casos mais gerais, onde a pergunta é especificamente sobre problemas com do framework e não relativos a modelagem, devo remover também?

Comment: Essa é uma das *tags* mais mal usadas do site. Eu tento dar uma arrumada, mas não consigo arrumar tudo sozinho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, como a pergunta não é sobre o padrão de projeto MVC, e já tem a tag [asp.net-mvc-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4), [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) pode ser removida.